# toggle switch css3 animate from left to right responsive

Tags: css, checkbox, input, jquery-animate, toggleswitch

Currently I am building a simon game clone and I thought I'd like to modernize a bit.

Anyway, I was able to find a blog on how to make toggle switch with only CSS3 (http://callmenick.com/post/css-toggle-switch-examples)

However, since I am trying to make this web responsive, I made the container (label) with width : 100%.

I am having hard time figuring out how to make the toggle switch itself move towards the end of the container at any width viewport.

```css
body {
  background: skyblue;
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; }

.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  margin-top: 10px; }

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1px; }

#green {
  background: #39d565;
  border-top-left-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #0d934b;
  bottom: 6px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear; }
  #green:active {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #0d934b; }

#red {
  background: #d23a51;
  border-top-right-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #711515;
  bottom: 6px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear; }
  #red:active {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #711515; }

#blue {
  background: #09f;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #06c;
  bottom: 6px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear; }
  #blue:active {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #06c; }

#yellow {
  background: #FD9A01;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #916828;
  bottom: 6px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear; }
  #yellow:active {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #916828; }

.score {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 3px 2px black; }

.control-panel {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  height: 15vh;
  background: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 10px; }
  .control-panel #on-off-btn {
    width: 33.3333%; }
  .control-panel #level {
    background: orange;
    width: 33.3333%; }
  .control-panel #start {
    background: purple;
    width: 33.3333%; }

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden; }

.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none; }

input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-left: 5px; }

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: ""; }

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s; }

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 38px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s; }

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196; }

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 20px; }

@media screen and (min-width: 426px) {
  .container {
    width: 426px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; } }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>Simon Game FCC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="game">
        <div id="green" class="button"></div>
        <div id="red" class="button"></div>
        <div id="blue" class="button"></div>
        <div id="yellow" class="button"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="score">
        <h2>Score: 0 </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="control-panel">
        <div id="on-off-btn">
          <input id="cmn-toggle-1"type="checkbox" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round">
          <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
          <p>Off/On</p>
        </div>
        <div id="level"></div>
        <div id="start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected result, use below option

Change margin-left:20px to 90% to work as expected

```
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 90%;
```

}

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jAYojX

Comment: I've tried that, but it looks like the toggle itself overlaps its container

Comment: Did you try % or px before ?, because giving 20px will make it incomplete toggle

Comment: I would like to. 
Essentially the effect I want is changing the position left:0 px to right:0 px

Comment: the one codepen works but needs to be modified to look better right ?

Comment: yes exactly. You can see that it goes over its container.
I'm suspecting this is because I am using pseudo collector :after

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117498/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-alejandro).